# Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address Address already in use

Tags: php, websocket, bind

I have a PHPWebSocket application, and my server.php has starting part code like that:

```
$Server = new PHPWebSocket(); 
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 3306);
```

and PHPLibrary code I have like that:

```
    // server state functions
    function wsStartServer($host, $port) {
    if (isset($this->wsRead[0])) return false;
    if (!$this->wsRead[0] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
        return false;

    if (!socket_set_option($this->wsRead[0], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
        socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
        return false;
    }
        if (!socket_bind($this->wsRead[0], $host, $port)) {
            socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
            return false;
        if (!socket_listen($this->wsRead[0], 10)) {
            socket_close($this->wsRead[0]);
            return false;
        }
```

When I used this in local computer, then everything worked fine, but when I inserted this on ssh hosting, i have got all the time the same error:

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [48]: Address already in use in /usr/home/rafaluf/class.PHPWebSocket.php on line 110

Where is the problem here? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running MySQL on this box? 3306 is the default MySQL port

Comment: You must read the message. It can't be clearer. **Address already in use**. Googling only that would tell you about ports, what they are etc. -1 for being lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the port number, cause 3306 is MySQL default port number and check the ip SERVER too

$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', XXXX);